# Can we suggest posting on the forums for too localized?

Tags: feature-request, close-reasons

On the closed as too localized text, we say that the question won't help other people, but we don't suggest where they should go now.

Since Canonical advertises the Ask Ubuntu community (e.g. in Ubiquity) as a feature of Ubuntu, users think that this is a support venue, which it is, but in a separate way than the forums (we want a question to be applicable to everyone). Basically, I think we should say something like:

> This question is unlikely to help any future visitors; it is only relevant to a small geographic area, a specific moment in time, or an extraordinarily narrow situation that is not generally applicable to the worldwide audience of the internet. For help making this question more broadly applicable, see the FAQ. *If you can't make your question more generalized, try asking on the [Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/forum.php).*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I really like this idea, although awesome would be a way for moderators to be able to send question to the Ubuntu forum (Notifying the user) in cases where they can not be handled here. Like a relation between the forum and askubuntu since both places do an excellent job at helping the community. It could also be extended to notify users in IRC channels (Even country specific ones).

I might be carrying on here but it would be a good futuristic idea to have "Unity" between Forum, Askubuntu and IRC. All 3 could be Technology Helpers for the community.

Basically F.A.I.T.H (Forum, Askubuntu & IRC Technology Helpers), where end users have an excellent chance of getting help about Ubuntu.

Comment: FAITH in Ubuntu.  I like that.

Comment: did this never go anywhere?

Comment: Don't know, have not heard anything about this but I am sure an idea similar will appear. Would be nice to get an email about it so I can help.